# When using CefSharp SendKeyEvent, I am unable to type the document

Tags: c#, cefsharp

c#, Cefsharp winform 88.2.90
ExecuteJavascriptAsync and OffScreen are not my considerations.

I type in a Word document like this
*1234567890*

CefSharp is typing on the Input Element like this
*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*

However, when I type in Word and Cefsharp types at the same time, my focus shifts to the Cefsharp Input Element, and Cefsharp enters the wrong value.

For example, CefSharp enters the wrong value this way
*a1b2c3d4e5f6..............................*

Even if I'm typing, CefSharp enter the correct values.
How can I solve this problem?

```
void ClickandType(string inputString)
{
    var host = browser.GetBrowserHost();
    host.SendMouseMoveEvent(xPosition, yPosition, false, CefEventFlags.None);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    host.SendMouseClickEvent(xPosition, yPosition, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    host.SendMouseClickEvent(xPosition, yPosition, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.None);
    foreach (var c in inputString)
    {
        host.SendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent { WindowsKeyCode = c, Type = KeyEventType.Char });
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You'll likely need to switch over to using the DevTools protocol, specifically https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/#method-dispatchKeyEvent https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3165 http://cefsharp.github.io/api/89.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_DevTools_Input_InputClient_DispatchKeyEventAsync.htm

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for the advice. I will try.it :)